# Javascript Parse Promise function gives 'success/error was not called' error

Tags: javascript, promise

I want my Parse cloud code to iterate through an object's instances and `console.log` the `itemCondition` property of each once. Based on my research, because this is an asynch http request, it seems the best way to do this is with a promise statement. When running my attempt below however, I get an error stating `Error: success/error was not called`. I was under the impression that you don't use explicit success/error statements when writing a promise function, am I not understanding that right?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {
    //defines which parse class to iterate through
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    var promises = [];
    //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
    query.limit(10);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        //the pinging ebay part
        for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
            promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: url,
                params: {
                    'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
                    'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
                    'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                    'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
                    'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
                    'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
                    'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
                    'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                    'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                    'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
                    'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
                    'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
                    //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
                    'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
                    'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
                }
            }));
            console.log(results[i].get('itemCondition'));
        }
        Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(results) {
            for (i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            {
                var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
                response.success(httpresponse);
                console.log(results[i].get('itemCondition'));
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('error!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ghobs I ran your code through an IDE and removed a extraneous trailing comma after params:{}, Not sure if it was affecting your code but iirc it would have choked IE8.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I'm still getting the same error after fixing it though.

Comment: Ghobs, I think that response is a promise? Once a promise is resolved it cannot be resolved again. So you probably need to put that (`response.success(httpresponse);`) outside of the loop. I don't have access to this API, but if you could build a fiddle I could play with I would help you through this. Is there a CDN for Parse, do you need an account?

Comment: @Shanimal I see what you mean. I tried putting the response call outside of the loop, and causes the app to crash. Unfortunately you can't run it through fiddle, as you need access to my parse database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ghobs, there's a few things happening here, let's take them one by one:

1. The error `Error: success/error was not called`, is called when the overall Parse `response.success()` or `response.error()` is not called.  This is required for the client to receive a response.  Remember `success` or `error` is called once.
2. You have the right idea with the array of functions going to the `when()` function, but I think what you want to happen is, to execute all the httpRequest methods and then take the response from those and deal with them within the `then`.   The issue with what you have here, is you're executing the `httpRequest` and putting the response on the array, when really you want the array to be an array of **Promises**. According to the docs (https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when) the `when` function takes promises as arguments, or as an array, and executes them.  So you need to create an array of actual `Parse.Promise` objects, and as of this writing, `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` returns a `Promise` object.  So you're in luck!  So what you need to do is wrap the call to `httpRequest` within a function, that yields you the `Promise` return of httpRequest.

For example

```
    promises.push((function() {
         var httpRequestPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: url,
            params: {
                'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
                'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
                'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
                'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
                'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
                'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
                'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
                'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
                'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
                //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
                'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
                'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
            }
        })
      return httpRequestPromise;
    })());
```

1. Finally what you do with the response.  The API documentation for `then()` which can be found here (http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#then) , says that the `then` will give you a function that has all your Promise responses as `arguments`.  But because you're in a loop and you don't know how many arguments will be (one for each call), you can just use the generic `arguments` reserved var.  For example let's say you wanted to collect the responses from your request:

   ```
   Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
       var allResponses = []
       for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
       {
           var httpResponse = arguments[i];
           var responseObj = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
           allResponses.push(responseObj);
       }
       // and by the way if this is the end of your function, then here you can call
       response.success(allResponses);
   }, function(err) {
       console.log('error!');
       response.error();
   });
   ```

Hope this helps, and good luck Ghobs!